Printing diamond Pattern in python
[enter image description here][1]I have to print a diamond pattern in Python, but the diamond is different. There are 2 input variables m and n. m represent the number of the blocks where n represents the head on that block, and if the lines on the head are greater than 2, then lines () are inside the block [Head_lines - 2 = number of '']. check the attached picture for reference

I got this code, and I still haven't figured out how to remove the space at the end of the line.
Can someone help me solve this pattern?
It's almost done Thanks to @SIGHUP

You'll find that f-strings are very useful for this exercise. You can calculate the number of underscores based on the second parameter passed to your function.
Something like this:
def picture(m, n):
    print((f" {'/\\'*n} " * m)[:-1])
    z = (n - 1) * 2
    print(f"/ {'_'*z} \\" * m)
    print(f"\\ {' '*z} /" * m)
    print((f" {'\\/'*n} " * m)[:-1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    picture(3, 5)

Output:
 /\/\/\/\  /\/\/\/\  /\/\/\/\ 
/ ______ \/ ______ \/ ______ \
\        /\        /\        /
 \/\/\/\/  \/\/\/\/  \/\/\/\/ 


the output is right, but it has a extra space at the end of top and bottom '/' and '/'

Hey! Thanks i figured out a way. I used rstrip for removing the space. Thanks for the help though

@DhirajBadlani You're right. Visually it was OK but there was indeed a redundant trailing space on the top and bottom lines. Answer fixed
